# Show an attribute from other model in blade (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I´ve got this exception in my blade template. I made a relation between my two models (RegisteredCourses y User) and I can see it works in the rest of Blade´s template, except form.blade.php

***Trying to get property 'user' of non-object (View: C:\laragon\www\hr-english\resources\views\registeredCourse\form.blade.php) (View: C:\laragon\www\hr-english\resources\views\registeredCourse\form.blade.php)***

My idea is to show in my blade template the name of the user, but I need in the value of input the correspondant user_id.

I don´t what is the correct approach to this problem.

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('course_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="course_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">Course</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="course_id" name="course_id">
            <option value="" style="display: none;" {{ old('course_id', optional($registeredCourse)->course_id ?: '') == '' ? 'selected' : '' }} disabled selected>Select course</option>
            @foreach ($courses as $key => $course)
                <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('course_id', optional($registeredCourse)->course_id) == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                    {{ $course }}
                </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

        {!! $errors->first('course_id', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('user_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="status_course" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control" name="user_id" type="text" id="user_id" value="{{ old('user_id', optional($registeredCourse->user->name)) }}" minlength="1" placeholder="Enter name here..."> <!--Problwm here-->
        {!! $errors->first('name', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('status_course') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="status_course" class="col-md-2 control-label">Status Course</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control" name="status_course" type="text" id="status_course" value="{{ old('status_course', optional($registeredCourse)->status_course) }}" minlength="1" placeholder="Enter status course here...">
        {!! $errors->first('status_course', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: try `optional(optional($registeredCourse)->user)->name` instead of `optional($registeredCourse->user->name)` [not tested]

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn´t work. Mi idea is to grab the user_id in the value of the input to store in the database, but I would like to show the name to the user in the form.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op): `$registeredCourse->user->name ?? null` instead of  `optional($registeredCourse->user->name)` in your blade

UPS: [Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/tgEkZ) showing how this works depending on whether `$registeredCourse->user` is set or not.

Comment: Thank you. Not working. I do not why, but it seems impossible, to show the name and take the value to store in the databases

Comment: I tested it, it works in both cases, if the user is set or not. Here's a demo link for you: https://3v4l.org/tgEkZ

Comment: Pavel, I am begginer. I do not if this is a silly question, but I am using Laravel, your code in my blade template will be something like this: value="{{ old('user_id', $registeredCourse->user->name ?? null }}"  Am I right?

Comment: Almost! `value="{{ old('user_id', $registeredCourse->user->name ?? null) }}` . You missed the final `)`. Good luck with Laravel! Feel free to ask more questions, you'll get good support here :)